# How to apply canvas to whole document or how to draw on whole document?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have .aspx page and i want to draw on whole document using JS.I'm newbie in JS...
For example this code(in my aspx) allow me to draw on 200x200 area:

```
    <canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>

    <script type ="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');       
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.5)";
    ctx.fillRect(30, 30, 55, 50);
    });
    </script>
```

How to draw on whole document?Because I can't write something like:

```
   <canvas id="canvas" $(document).width() $(document).height()></canvas>
```

I want to draw a transparent rectangle on whole document and see the page content behind.

Here is the solution(thnx to kirilloid):
CSS:

```
    #canvas {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    }
```

JS:

```
    function updateCanvas(width,height) {
    var $canvas = $("#canvas");
    $canvas.attr('width', $(document).width())
    $canvas.attr('height', $(document).height());
    var ctx = $canvas.get(0).getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.5)";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height/2);
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 200, 0, 0.5)";
    ctx.fillRect(0, height/2, width, height);
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
    updateCanvas($(document).width(), $(document).height())
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to draw on the page itself. You'll need to make canvas fit whole window and update its sizes (and redraw) on window resize.

If you change its sizes in CSS, canvas is only stretched like images do. If you change `width` and `height` attributes, then it's cleared.

CSS:

```
#canvas {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

The code:

```
function updateCanvas() {
    var $canvas = $("#canvas");
    $canvas.attr('width', $(document).width())
    $canvas.attr('height', $(document).height());
    var ctx = $canvas.get(0).getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.5)";
    ctx.fillRect(30, 30, 55, 50);
}
$(window).on('resize', updateCanvas); // maybe, add some thresholding
updateCanvas();
```

UPD: Just came up with more performant solution: set canvas sizes from `window.screen` and put it into `overflow: hidden` container fitting whole window. Then you won't need to redraw or resize canvas at all (multi-display users can still be a problem).